# How to align labels with input fields in bootstrap?

Tags: apex, visualforce, bootstrap

I have added bootstrap on vf page but my labels and input field blocks are not in parallel. Please help me in aligning.

```
<apex:page title="Availability Check" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" controller="AvailabilityCheckController" showHeader="false"  >

  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
 <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>-->
  <apex:includescript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.cscfga__jQuery_min)}"/>
  <apex:includescript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap, 'bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')}"/>
  <link href="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap, 'bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Availability_Check_CSS)}"/> 

<apex:form id="formid">
<div class="container-fluid" style="color:#963821">
    <h2>Address Search</h2>
    <!-- panel for Address A -->
    <div class="row" style="color:#007681">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-right:20px; border-right: 1px solid #ccc;">           
            <h3>Address A</h3>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 text-justify" style="color:#CE7800">
                    <h4>Street</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                    <input id="addressInputStreetA" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Enter Street"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="color:#CE7800">
                    <h4>Postcode</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                    <input id="addressInputPostcodeA" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Enter Postcode"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="color:#CE7800">
                    <h4>Co-ordinate X</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                    <input id="addressInputXA" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Enter X Co-ord."></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="color:#CE7800">
                    <h4>Co-ordinate Y</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                    <input id="addressInputYA" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Enter Y Co-ord."></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="space10"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                    <input type="button" value="Search" class="buttonRound_EF btnText_EF" ></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                    <input type="button" value="Reset" class="buttonRound_EF btnText_EF" ></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <hr/>
                <!-- panel for Address A display -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                    <div id="adressesA" class="label_EF panel2_EF"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr/>
        </div> 
        <!-- panel for Address A -->      
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h3>Address B</h3>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="color:#CE7800">
                    <h4>Street</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                    <input id="addressInputStreetB" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Enter Street"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="color:#CE7800">
                    <h4>Postcode</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                    <input id="addressInputPostcodeB" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Enter Postcode"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="color:#CE7800">
                    <h4>Co-ordinate X</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                    <input id="addressInputXB" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Enter X Co-ord."></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="color:#CE7800">
                    <h4>Co-ordinate Y</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                    <input id="addressInputYB" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Enter Y Co-ord."></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="space10"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                    <input type="button" value="Search" class="buttonRound_EF btnText_EF" ></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                    <input type="button" value="Reset" class="buttonRound_EF btnText_EF" ></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <hr/>
                <!-- panel for Address B display -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                    <div id="adressesB" class="label_EF panel2_EF"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr/>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Container for Availability Check -->
<div class="container-fluid" style="color:#963821">
    <h2>Availability Check</h2> 
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="color:#CE7800">
            <h4>Offer</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedOffer}" size="1" id="compOfferID"> 
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!offers}" /> 
            </apex:selectList>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                <input type="button" value="Check" class="buttonRound_EF btnText_EF" ></input>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <hr/>
            <!-- panel for Availability Check display -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                <div id="checks" class="label_EF panel2_EF"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr/>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]